Average value of a function in a given interval considering only integer values within interval
As a well known fact, if $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ is an integratable function, then we can define the mean value of $f$ on $[a,b]$, denoted as $\bar{y}$, by setting
$$\bar {{y}}\:=\:\frac{1}{{b}−{a}}\int^b_a{f}\left({x}\right){dx} \\ $$
but this takes all possible rational value of $x$ and sum them up and then gives a average.
What if we only want to calculate the average of $f(x)$ in the given interval $[a,b]$ but this time we want to consider only the value of $x$ that are integers and then summing and calculate average.
For a more clearity what I'm trying to ask consider an example.
The sum of first $n$ positive integers is famously known to be  $\dfrac{{n}\left({n}+\mathrm{1}\right)}{\mathrm{2}} \\ $
Let's do it by integral approach. Define $f:[0,n]\to\mathbb{R}$, $f(x)=x$, and we can set
$$\overline {{f}\left({x}\right)}\:=\:\frac{\mathrm{1}}{{n}−\mathrm{0}}\underset{\mathrm{0}} {\overset{{n}} {\int}}{xdx}=\frac{{n}^{\mathrm{2}} }{\mathrm{2}{n}}=\frac{{n}}{\mathrm{2}} \\ $$
Therefore, the sum of first $n$ integers $S_n$ can be computed by$${S}_{{n}} =\overline {{f}\left({x}\right)}.{n}=\frac{{n}}{\mathrm{2}}.{n}=\frac{{n}^{\mathrm{2}} }{\mathrm{2}} \\ $$
$$ \\ $$
as this is different from $\dfrac{{n}\left({n}+\mathrm{1}\right)}{\mathrm{2}} \\ $ as expected because it's adding all possible rational numbers in interval $0$ to $n$. Surprisingly this sum of only integer is greater than the sum of all possible rationals I'm saying all possible rationals because limit is taken to infinity and intervals are made very small as assumption during derivation of the average formula.
So firstly why is;
$$\frac{{n}^{\mathrm{2}} }{\mathrm{2}}<\frac{{n}\left({n}+\mathrm{1}\right)}{\mathrm{2}} \\ $$
but we are expecting the opposite. And finally is there any way to mold our average formula to calculate average or sum over only integral values like above result of sum of first $n$ integers ?

Your confusions are much too great in number and scope to be dealt with comprehensively here. I strongly suggest you hire a tutor.

hahhahha its just curious i am

What do you mean by "all possible rational value" when you are defining the average?

For "All possible" consider the fact that when calculating mean we actually devide area under the function curve in interval [a,b] by length of the interval, and area as its visually obvious happens continuously from a to b in other it includes contribution of every rational number between the extremes of this interval in the form of infinitely many very very small intervals.

Sure i would be very grateful to have someone such a ready to cure this ... Thanks for such a honest comment It's actually a great motivation for me to try to dilute this ignorance myself too.....by the way can you kindly enlist some of my confident proclamation

Also posted to MO, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/477923/average-value-of-a-function-in-a-given-interval-considering-only-integer-values with no mention of the crosspost at either site, in violation of site customs.

Your question isn't 100% clear to me but I will try my best to explain what I think you are confused about.
We use $\frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^bf(x)\,dx$ for continuous functions which gives us the average value (you can also think of it as a measure of the center) of the function over the given interval. We can not use this for discrete functions, such as the sum of the first $n$ positive integers.
A helpful analogy is to think of a day's average temperature. There are infinitely many data points so we can't use the elementary $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^na_1$. In this case, we could use the average value theorem.
Now imagine we want to calculate the week's average temperature, and we are only given each day's average, that is, a set of 7 numbers). We can not use the average value theorem since we have a discrete function composed of 7 points and must calculate the average value using the standard formula.
